# Resolve wrong port Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I have set 2 different port with subdomain on each port. For example: port 8080 -> a.example.com and port 8081 -> b.example.com. But when I try to open a.example.com:8081 the browser loads the b.example.com:8081 web page (but the url not changing to b.example.com:8081) and vice versa. How to redirect to the correct port/subdomain, if we open a.example.com:8081 then it will automatically redirect to a.example.com:8080 or maybe to b.example.com:8081?

I am using Apache 2.4 and my vshost:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName a.example.com
    DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/a
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName b.example.com
    DocumentRoot D:/xampp/htdocs/b
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Apache isn't matching a named host on that port, it serves the default one which is the first one read from config files (which is why you'll see config files named like 00_default and such - the numeric part forces a sort order)

What you can do for your use case is specify a named host with the "wrong" name on each port that has any request sending a redirect to the correct combination of name and port.